# Terminal osx - file extraction by name in zips within zip

Tags: macos, terminal, unzip

I'm a newbie - I couldn't find a question like mine, so hope is not because is too obvious...

(With the terminal in osx) I aim at extracting to a specific folder in current directory all files with a specific name that are 2 levels of zips down, and clean everything except the specified folder.

The structure is:

- Tiles_##.zip

  1. ASTGTM2_#1#.zip

     - ASTGTM2_#1_1#_dem.tif
     - ASTGTM2_#1_2#_num.tif
  2. ASTGTM2_#2#.zip

     - ASTGTM2_#2_2#_dem.tif
     - ASTGTM2_#2_2#_num.tif
  3. ASTGTM2_#3#.zip 
     ...

In Name_#Number#, #Number# is a series of letters and numbers that identify each file.

In 'pseudo-commands':

```
unzip Tiles_*.zip | unzip ASTGTM2_*.zip | mkdir DEM | mv **/*_dem.tif ./DEM | rm -r But_DEM
```

I've tried with different convinations without success...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use a combination of `-p` to extract to `stdout` (for piping) and wildcard use for your extracted files. Read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
mkdir tmp DEM
for i in Tiles_*.zip; do unzip $i -d tmp; done
for i in tmp/ASTGTM2_*.zip; do unzip $i -d DEM; done
rm -rf tmp
```

This uses the `-d` option to specify the directory to extract files to.

Comment: Thanks nneonneo! that's a good option to upzip everything that's in the parent zip and leave it in DEM folder. I'd like to go one step further, though, a leave in DEM folder with nothing but the *_dem.tif files. I'm trying, but not managing so far...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it... thanks to using nneonneo syntax, which I didn't know.

```
mkdir tmp ZIPs DEMs
for i in Tiles_*.zip; do unzip $i -d ZIPs; done
for i in ZIPs/ASTGTM2_*.zip; do unzip $i -d tmp; done
for i in tmp/ASTGTM2_*/*_dem.tif; do mv $i -d DEMs; done
rm -rf tmp ZIPs *.zip
```

This puts all *_dem.tif files into a new folder, DEMs, and deletes all the rest

Still it looks a bit too long and not very elegant, but it does the job...